# Mat-Select does not take default parent width of 180px of .mat-form-field-infix (Edge Browser)

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

Mat-Select should be 180px which is the width of the mat-infix container

**Problem**

Select spans 100% if width of form field is not set

This form field has no explicit width set, however the select element is not contained to the 180px with of the mat-form-field-infix which contains it. it works fine on all browser except Edge(Latest Version in Windows 10)

**Normal behavior** Chrome

[image: https://www.screencast.com/t/SR3NWkOJ]

**Abnormal behavior** Edge

[image: https://www.screencast.com/t/oA3q8LzLZrIc]

Also its and Open issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14406) I need some workaround till they fix

Comment: could you create a stackblitz example?

Comment: @StepUp check this link in chrome and edge    https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Comment: This sounds like a bug report, not a question. Why are you posting this here?

Comment: @G.Tranter Every bug has a solution I am posting it here so that if any one know's the solution . In my case i need solution whatever it is. I just need a workaround till they fix that

Comment: Right - but your post doesn't ask for a solution/workaround - it just looks like a report that was copied and pasted from the GitHub issue.

Comment: Forgot about writing provide me Solution. and i just copy because this issue was not asked on stackoverflow. So may be i get help form here rather then github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself that just wrap the material `mat-select` inside some `div` a give it the `width` equal to `input`.

Like this

```
<div class="select-cover">
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Records Per Page</mat-label>
                <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedPageSizePerformers" (ngModelChange)="selectChange()">
                  <mat-option [value]="10">10</mat-option>
                  <mat-option [value]="25">25</mat-option>
                  <mat-option [value]="50">50</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
```

And Style it

```
.select-cover{
  width: 198px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that this is an [Angular Material bug](https://github.com/bwsw/cloudstack-ui/issues/1486), you could post a feedback about this issue to Angular Material.

As a workaround, you could try to use the html  element, and use the `matNativeControl` attribute and the mat related CSS styles.

Like this:

```
<select class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored" id="mat-input-0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" required="" _ngcontent-evs-c20="" matnativecontrol="">
      <option value="volvo" _ngcontent-evs-c20="">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab" _ngcontent-evs-c20="">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes" _ngcontent-evs-c20="">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi" _ngcontent-evs-c20="">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am restricted to use Angular material Components which is mat-select. Anyway Thanks for your time. I will post the feed back on GitHub